# PHPUnit configuring and running a group test [Laravel 5.6]

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have this phpunit.xml with @somegroup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">/tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <groups>
        <include>
            <group>somegroup</group>
        </include>
    </groups>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Then I have this method with @group tag:

```
/**
 * @group somegroup
 */
public function testStatus()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

And then I run test group tag in command line, like this:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit --group somegroup
```

And I get this:

```
No tests executed!
```

Test command without @group tag works:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is it Laravel that does not support @group?

Comment: Remove the `<groups>` section from your XML, then try the command line with `--group` again. Does that work?

Comment: No, it does not. But I got it. It is due to Laravel peculiarity. If you run Unit (folder), this is enough: vendor\bin\phpunit --group somegroup. But if you run Feature (folder), then you have to specify suite to get test running, then you can call tag: vendor\bin\phpunit  --testsuite Feature Tests  --group somegroup. I was running Feature. BTW: dropping groups from xml was a good call. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it's working! One question: is this a typo in your XML? `<directory suffix="Test.php">/tests/Feature</directory>` (Note that the path is absolute, rather than relative as I'd expect: `./tests/Feature`.)

Comment: Yeah ... it is not 'Laravel peculiarity' but my brain telling me it is not a good idea to work at 3 am. Specifying --testsuite must have compensated for that missing dot. Because, when I added it, --testsuite was not needed anymore. Sorry I wasted your time. Much appreciated thou.

Comment: Yup, `--testsuite` does in fact select it, rather than using filesystem globbing. Glad it's working!